# Ограничение на ввод в поле input

Tags: html

Каким образов в поле ввода `<input>` можно запретить вводить число **0** , и в этом же поле разрешить ввод максимум двух символов? 
желательно без JavaScript

Comment: Символов или чисел? Это не одно и тоже. Если символов, то `min` не подойдет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У элемента `input` можно указать два атрибута `maxlength` и `min`. Первый атрибут поддерживается всеми браузерами, второй появился в HTML5 и поддерживается не всеми. Подробнее о поддержке [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/min). Если Вас не удовлетворяет такая поддержка браузеров, то тогда запрет ввода нуля можно решить только при помощи JavaScript

Comment: без типа поля `number`, `min` бесполезен, а в условии говорится про символы, а не числа.

Comment: @Alex min и для number бесполезен! :)))

Answer (score 4):

В данном случае можно использовать атрибут [`pattern`](//webref.ru/html/input/pattern):

```html
<form action="//google.com/search" target="_blank">
  <input name="q" value="www" pattern="([^0].?|0[^0])" autofocus>
  <button>GO</button>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9wdyptg3/

> **Примечание**. Смотрите фиддл, так как в песочнице Стека пример не сработает (смотрите комментарии к ответу) .

Comment: в таком случае запрещает ввести **0**, не подходит к сожалению.

Comment: @Денис, исправил регулярку (2 раза :)) ... так а вам что нужно? > `запретить вводить число 0` ...

Comment: @RomanGrinyov не работает в сниппете, потому, что в сниппете не стоит разрешение `'allow-forms' permission is not set`

Comment: @RomanGrinyov Получается, нельзя ввести "02"?

Comment: @cronfy, сделал, теперь работает как нужно.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov ага, правда теперь можно ввести "00".

Comment: @cronfy, допилил :)

Answer (score 3):

Вот так:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity "min="1" max="99">
```

В IE поддерживается с 10 версии.

Документация: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp

Можно добавить еще атрибут `maxlength="2"`, это ограничит максимальное количество вводимых символов, но будет не очень удобно для ввода. Зато поддерживается старыми браузерами.